# How can I describe an assumption of a past event?

Tags: past-tense, conditionals, subjunctive-mood

Assume that Alice took an exam last week and she got its result yesterday. So she knows whether she passed the exam or not.

Now here is Bob. He does not know the result of Alice's exam yet. And Bob is explaining Alice's situation to you:

> If she did not pass the exam, she has to leave the collage.

I think that this sentence is wrong, because the IF-part sounds a subjunctive mood, so Bob would not believe that Alice passed the exam. But at least Bob can imagine both situations.

How can I correct Bob's statement?

Comment: If she didn't pass, she would have to leave. If she hasn't passed, she will have to leave.

Comment: Just because there's an *if* in the sentence doesn't mean it's in the subjunctive mood. Sometimes (and often), a conditional (with an *if*) is just a conditional … In short, there's nothing wrong with the sentence as it's written. Except that it's **college**, not *collage*.